# Can I view source-code of python built-in function while debugging with pdb?

Tags: python, python-2.7, debugging, pdb, built-in

How can I examine the code  of a python built-in function, for example step into `sum()`?

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum.

I expected to  see what `sum()` does using the code below and `s` command in pdb:

```
import pdb
def adder(nums):
  x = sum(nums)
  return x

pdb.set_trace()
print adder([1, 2, 3,4])
```

Comment: It depends how `sum()` is being executed. Some of the Python modules are written in C (to increase performance) and cannot be stepped through in `pdb`. UPDATE: I just checked the Python source code for sum and it does appear to be written in C.

Comment: The VAST majority (all?) of python ``builtins`` are written in C.

Comment: @aruisdante Checked the Python/bltinmodule.c file and it does appear that the `__builtin__` module is written entirely in C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some of the Python modules are written in C (to increase performance) and cannot be stepped through in `pdb`. If you *really* want to see what's going on in these functions it's possible, but not trivial. To examine C functions I typically use the GNU Debugger (GDB) and  compile Python with debugging symbols enabled.

1. Download the Python source code found at https://www.python.org/downloads/
2. Untar the Python source code | `tar xzvf Python-2.7.6.tar.gz`
3. Enter the untarred directory and run the configuration script using | `./configure`
4. Compile with debug symbols | `make -g`
5. Start your custom compiled debug Python with the GNU Debugger | `gdb ./python`
6. Set a breakpoint in GDB for the `sum()` call | `b bltinmodule.c:builtin_sum`.
7. Run your script from GDB (I called mine sumtest.py) | `run ~/sumtest.py`

The first thing that happens is you get prompted for your PDB call. Continue using `c`.

The next break is in the middle of the sum function in C. You can use `info locals` to list all the local variables. Just like in PDB `c` is used to continue execution to the next breakpoint amd `s` is used to step through single instructions.