# In PyCharm, ctrl+click on a method takes you to that methods declaration but for print() & other methods I only see the method header, but no body

Tags: python, java, python-3.x, intellij-idea, pycharm

I'm a Java programmer, trying to set up my python/PyCharm IDEA environment and there is a feature that I love in Java/IntelliJ where I can ctrl+click a method like println in `System.out.println()` and it will take me to the `println()` method declaration where **I can see the "method body"** as well. And for python/PyCharm it does the same thing, except, the **"method body" isn't shown**. I have 2 pics to show what I'm talking about:

In Python & PyCharm, when I ctrl+click on the `print()` function to "Go To Declaration" I don't see any actual code, only the method header... 
[image]

But In Java & IntelliJ Ultimate, when I ctrl+click on the `System.out.printlin()` method to "Go To Declaration" I do see all the actual code. 
[image]

So is it even possible to set up python/PyCharm IDEA to allow for the whole method body to be shown like it does in the Java picture? Or is there something I'm misunderstanding about Python that doesn't allow for this kind of capability.

Comment: Assuming you are using CPython, `print` is implemented in C: I don't know of any Python IDE that would show you that implementation, as opposed to the Python stub that you do see. (And I'm not sure how it would be possible without the source code of CPython, which usually isn't included when you install).

Comment: Yes, CPython. & so u said it should be possible with the source code of CPython? Do u think there's anyway I could download it & have it function like it does in Java? All I want is to read what code gets executed when I call a function, it's a tremendous learning tool for me & has helped me a lot in Java, I'm constantly going in & out of the Java Source Code, sometimes I spend literal hours in it. But for python, c++, JavaScript, & TypeScript... I can never view the source like Java. **Even if I use the debugger, & try to step into the `print()` function it doesnt step into.** Is that normal?

Comment: *"Do u think there's anyway I could download it & have it function like it does in Java?"* Do Java IDEs do this though? In your example, you show how the IDE can show you the Java source code of `println`, because that method is implemented in Java itself. But does the IDE ever **step into the C source code of the JVM implementation**? That's the Java equivalent of what you're looking for in Python here.

Comment: The CPython source is here on Github: https://github.com/python/cpython. But having the source is one thing; being able to automatically infer what piece of C code is the implementation of Python `print` is a different and more complex thing.

Comment: No it doesn't step into the C source code, it just shows the Java source code. And I think I see what you're saying now. There is no python source code for `print` like there's java source code for `println`.  But I can't step into the `str().lower()` or `str().split` either, so do they fall under the same category as print()?

Comment: Regarding how you might attempt this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26198847/can-i-step-into-python-library-code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150375/how-do-you-break-into-the-debugger-from-python-source-code?rq=3 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23319883/can-i-view-source-code-of-python-built-in-function-while-debugging-with-pdb?rq=3 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58343685/how-to-walk-through-python-opcode-while-debugging-cpython https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57278643/the-optimal-way-to-set-a-breakpoint-in-the-python-source-code-while-debugging-cp?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: ...but all of this involves a bit of manual work, I don't think any IDE has integrated it.

Comment: Regarding `str` methods, yes they're also implemented in C. For example `lower()` is here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c523ce0f434582580a3721e15cb7dd6b56ad0236/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L11830 Generally, heavily used classes like `str` tend to be implemented in C, because the performance gain is most noticeable for the most used classes.

Comment: Okay, I see, I just tried it with the `webbrowser.get()` method and it worked like It does in the Java screenshot. So I just can't view the source code, generally, for heavily used classes like `str`. Okay that makes sense. Thank you :) and so am I kinda right to think that it's the same when I try to view the source code in c++, javascript, and TypeScript when I can't see the method body...the source code doesn't exist in that lang because the implementation is written in something else? And the only way to view it would be getting the source for the lang it's implementation is written in?

Comment: I think that's right for JS and TypeScript. Not so sure for C++, because generally the libraries are written in C++ itself. But I don't know enough about C++ IDEs to understand what is and isn't available, sorry!

Comment: No problem! This is something that has been bugging me for a long time but I never knew how to google it or ask the question. But now I know. Thank you :)